# {$X_n$} be a sequence of r.v. and N is a $\mathbb{N}$-valued r.v. Prove $X_N$ is also a r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let {$X_n$} be a sequence of random variables for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $N$ be a random variable with a value of positive integer.

{$X_n$} and $N$ are defined as on the same probability space ($\Omega, F, P$), and I would like to prove that $X_N$ is also a random variable.

How should I define mapping on $\Omega$ to start the proof? What is the next process I need to consider as well to get the right conclusion? Does it suffice to prove $X_N$ is $F$-measurable?

Comment: $$[X_N\in B]=\bigcup_n[X_n\in B]\cap[N=n]$$

Comment: ... or $X_N = \sum_{n} X_n 1_{\{N=n\}}$

Comment: @Did I'm sorry I'm commenting on the problem a bit late, but the property you stated is enough to prove the statement right? Since $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it's closed under intersections and unions, and each of the set that we intersect/union are in $F$, since $X_n$'s and $N$ are measurable?

Comment: @pilotmath Exactly. (It is somewhat heartening to read a comment understanding the problem at hand, even two years after the fact, on a page where the accepted answer does not address the question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, $X_N$ is the mapping that takes $\omega\in\Omega$ to the number $X_{N(\omega)}(\omega)$.